Laravel appending attribute results to out of memory
In a model OrderItem I'm trying to append coupon value through accessing the Order relationship like below:
public function getCouponValueAttribute() {

        if($this->order->coupon_data) {
            if(!$this->sale && !$this->gift) {
                return ($this->original_price * $this->quantity) - (($this->original_price * $this->quantity) - (($this->original_price * $this->quantity)*($this->order->coupon_data['percentage']/100)));
            }
        }

        return 0;
        
    }

This results to the server to run out of memory.
Order Relationship through Order model
 public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

The Order Model looks like below:
class Order extends Model
{
    use FilterQueryString;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $filters = ['in', 'inPayment', 'sort'];
    
    protected $appends = ['subtotal', 'discountTotal', 'discountTotal2', 'couponDiscount', 'shipping_details', 'shipping_product_name', 'gross_value', 'net_value', 'shipping_iso', 'generated_tracking_url', 'is_retail'];



    protected $casts = [
        'shipping_address' => 'array',
        'billing_address' => 'array',
        'shipping_option' => 'array',
        'coupon_data' => 'array',
        'customer' => 'array',
        'invoice' => 'array'
    ];

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }

    public function payment() {
        return $this->hasOne(PaymentDetail::class);
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function notes() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderNote::class);
    }

    public function added_payments() {
        return $this->hasMany(AddedPayment::class);
    }

    public function inPayment($query, $value) {
        $value = explode(",", $value);
        return $query->whereHas('payment', function($q) use ($value) {
            $q->whereIn('status', $value);
        });
    }

    public function country() {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Country::class, User::class, 'country_id', 'id', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function coupon() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Coupon::class);
    }

    public function points() {
        return $this->hasOne(LoyaltyPoint::class);
    }

    public function shipments() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderShipment::class);
    }

    public function scopeQuote($query) {
        return $query->where('quote', true)->orWhere('was_quote', true);
    }

    public function scopeActive($query) {
        return $query->whereIn('status', [1,2,3]);
    }

    public function getActiveItemsAttribute() {

        return array_filter($this->items->toArray(), function($q) {
            return $q['status'] == 1;
        });

    }

    public function getSubtotalAttribute() {

        $subtotal = 0;

        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            if($i->status) {
                $subtotal += $i->price * $i->quantity;
            }
        }

        return $subtotal;

    }


    public function getCouponDiscountAttribute() {

        $discount = 0;
        
        if($this->coupon_data) {
            foreach($this->items as $i) {
                if($i->status && !$i->sale && !$i->gift) {
                    $price = $i->bulk_price ? $i->bulk_price : $i->original_price;
                    $discount += ($price - $i->price) * $i->quantity;
                }
            }
        }

        return abs($discount);


    }

    public function getDiscountTotalAttribute() {

        $discount = 0;

       
        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            if($i->status) {
                $discount += ($i->original_price - $i->price) * $i->quantity;
            }
        }
        


        return abs($discount);


    }

    public function getNetValueAttribute() {

        $net_value = 0;

        
        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            $net_value += $i->price*$i->quantity;
        }
        

        return $net_value;


    }


    public function getShippingProfilesAttribute() {
        return  (array) [
                (object)[
                    'quantity' => 4,
                    'length' => 25, 
                    'width' => 20,
                    'height' => 10
                ],
                (object) [
                'quantity' => 8,
                'length' => 30.5, 
                'width' => 21.5,
                'height' => 20

                ],
                (object) [
                'quantity' => 15,
                'length' => 32, 
                'width' => 24,
                'height' => 24

                ],
                (object) [
                'quantity' => 20,
                'length' => 50, 
                'width' => 30,
                'height' => 20
                ],
                (object) [
                'quantity' => 30,
                'length' => 50, 
                'width' => 30,
                'height' => 25
                ],
                (object) [
                'quantity' => 40,
                'length' => 60, 
                'width' => 40,
                'height' => 20
                ],
                (object) [
                'quantity' => 50,
                'length' => 48, 
                'width' => 40,
                'height' => 30
                ],
                (object) [
                'quantity' => 60,
                'length' => 60, 
                'width' => 40,
                'height' => 25
            ]
            ];
    }

    public function getDhlPackagesAttribute() {

        $packages = [];
        $quantity = 0;

        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            $quantity += $i->quantity;
        }

        do {
            foreach($this->shipping_profiles as $key => $p) {
                      if($quantity > 0) {
                          if($quantity <= $p->quantity) {
                               $data = (object)[
                                  'weight' => number_format(floatVal((($p->length*$p->width*$p->height)/5000)), 2),
                                  'dimensions' => (object)[
                                      'length' => $p->length, 
                                      'width' => $p->width, 
                                      'height' => $p->height 
                                  ]
                                  ];
      
                              $quantity -= $p->quantity;
      
                              array_push($packages, $data);
      
                          }
                          else if ($key == array_key_last($this->shipping_profiles)) {
                            $data = (object)[
                                'weight' => number_format(floatVal((($p->length*$p->width*$p->height)/5000)), 2),
                                'dimensions' => (object)[
                                    'length' => $p->length, 
                                    'width' => $p->width, 
                                    'height' => $p->height 
                                ]
                                ];
    
                            $quantity -= $p->quantity;
    
                            array_push($packages, $data);
                          }
                  
                      }

            }
            

         
        }while($quantity > 0);

        return $packages;

    }

    public function getDiscountTotal2Attribute() {

        //Discount based on product discount

        $discount = 0;

        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            if($i->sale && $i->status) {
                $discount += ($i->original_price * $i->quantity) - ($i->price * $i->quantity);
            } 
        }

        return abs($discount);


    }

    public function getIsRetailAttribute() {

        if(isset($this->user->is_retail)) {

            if($this->user->is_retail) {
                return true; 
            }
        }


        return false;

    }

    public function getGrossValueAttribute() {

        $gross_value = 0;

        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            if($i->status) {
            
                $gross_value += $i->original_price * $i->quantity;
                
            }

        }

        return $gross_value;


    }


    public function getItemQuantityAttribute() {

        $quantity = 0; 

        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            if($i->status) {
                $quantity += $i->quantity;
            }
        };

        return $quantity;

    }

    public function getShippingDetailsAttribute() { 
        
    
        if(isset($this->shipping_option['shipping_option'])) {
            return $this->shipping_option['shipping_option'];
        }

        if(isset($this->shipping_option)) {
            return $this->shipping_option;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function getShippingProductNameAttribute() {


        if(isset($this->shipping_option['name'])) {
            return $this->shipping_option['name'];
        }

        if(isset($this->shipping_option['productName'])) {
            return $this->shipping_option['productName'];
        }

        return null;

    }

    public function getShippingIsoAttribute() {


        $country = Country::find($this->shipping_address['country_id']);

        return $country->iso2;

    }

    public function getGeneratedTrackingUrlAttribute() {

        if($this->shipping_company == 'dhl') {
            return 'https://www.dhl.com/gr-en/home/tracking.html?tracking-id='.$this->tracking_id;
        }
        if($this->shipping_company == 'speedex') {
            return 'http://www.speedex.gr/isapohi.asp';
        }
        if($this->shipping_company == 'fedex') {
            return 'https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?trknbr='.$this->tracking_id;
        }

        return null;

    }


    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($order) {
            $order->payment()->delete();
            $order->added_payments()->delete();
            $order->shipments()->delete();
            $order->items()->delete();
            $order->notes()->delete();
            $order->points()->delete();
        });

        static::updated(function($order) {
            Loyalty::calculateOrderPoints($order);
        });

        static::created(function($order) {
            Loyalty::calculateOrderPoints($order);
        });
    }
    
}

Probably the attribute I'm trying to append is creating a loop somewhere and the server is running out of memory, i can't figure it out.

it maybe has something to do with the $appends you define on the Order model

It sems that appends in order are doing a loop or something like that, try to remove one per one, also maybe it's causing the problem the fact that your doing a subquery for every OrderItem to get only one value, that's not the correct way, be careful

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
